# In Java, Azure Dynamic Refresh using Poll method doesn't work with spring boot 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I have a spring boot application on v3.0.0 and I have successfully integrated it with azure app configuration library to fetch the application configuration's into my app.

However I am facing issues with dynamic Refresh with Poll method as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-java-spring-app

I have followed all steps mentioned here and it is not refreshing configuration in my spring boot application on v.3.0.0. Also didn't gave any issue on logs too.

Now, As soon as I degraded my spring boot application version from 3.x.x to 2.7.9.
Dynamic refresh started to work without any issue.

**Has anyone else also has experienced similar issue of dynamic refresh with boot on 3.x.x ? or
Any idea of its fix in latest spring boot version ?**

PS: I have tried and tested with latest spring boot version also i.e. 3.0.4. It doesn't work with it too.

Also I am using latest version of app-config library. i.e

```
`<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
  <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>  
  <version>2.11.0</version> 
</dependency>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Charu Jain Currently, azure app configuration library is compatible with Spring Boot 2.7* as described in release notes [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/spring/spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config/CHANGELOG.md). Our product team is working on the version that works with Spring Boot 3 and ETA is April 2023 (subject to change based on other factors). I suggest you follow release notes on the latest updates. I hope this helps.